# How to return a Magento 404 page in nginx?

Tags: nginx, 404

I have some URLs that I are coming up as "soft 404s" with Google. I want to make them genuine 404s, but would like them to use Magento's 404 pages.

I am using NGINX with php-fpm and here is what I currently have:

```
if ($request_uri ~* "catalogsearch/result/index\/\/l/") {
  return 404;
}
```

This returns an NGINX 404, but I want a Magento (user friendly) 404.

Is there a way to achieve this?